# How to prompt category specified form in vue js

Tags: python, html, css, django, vue.js

In first step form we have one field category field.

1. if user enters "Real estate" based on that we need to prompt Real estate form in second step with some
   input fields like "total rooms", "square ft".
2. if user enters "IT Training" based on that category we need to prompt IT Training form in second step
   with some input fields like "Location", "Salary".

I have tried a lot this by capturing category from first form by using onchange event. I have written one condition but how to call that particular step 2 form after user enters based on that need too prompt user specified form.

```
       onChange(event) {
        var category = event.target.value
        if (category == "Real Estaste"){
        // Here I need to propt real estate form with some fields 
        // example fields are total rooms, square_ft.
      },
```

This is an example code of multi step form please help me to achieve this, Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>
<body>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Multistep Form In VueJs</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h3 class="text-success" align="center">Multistep Form In VueJs</h3>
      <br>
      <div class="container" id="app">
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
               <div class="panel-heading">Multistep Form In VueJs</div>
               <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
               
                  <fieldset v-if="step == 1">
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>Step 1: Search for category</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input style="width: 93%;" type="text" v-model="category" @change="onChange($event)" placeholder="Search your category"
                      name="category" maxlength="200" id="id_post_type">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <button @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                     </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  
                  
                  <fieldset v-if="step == 2">
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>Step 2: If you type school in category prompt this form</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fname">First Name:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="fname" name="fname">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="lname" name="lname">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <button @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                        <button @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                     </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  
                  
                  <fieldset v-if="step == 3">
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>Step 3: If you type college in category prompt this form</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="mobno">Mobile Number:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="mobno" name="mobno">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Address:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <textarea  class="form-control" name="address" v-model="address"></textarea>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <button @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
                        <button @click.prevent="submit()" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                     </div>
                  </fieldset>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
<script >
   var app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
           step:1,
           category:'',
           fname:'',
           lname:'',
           mobno:'',
           address:'',
       },
   methods:{
       onChange(event) {
        var category = event.target.value
        if (category == "Real Estaste"){
        // Here I need to propt real estate form with some fields 
        // example fields are total rooms, square_ft.
      },
       prev() {
           this.step--;
       },

       next() {
           this.step++;
       },  
       submit() {
           alert('Form Is Submitted.');      
       }   
   }  
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way is just add `v-if` inside `<fieldset v-if="step == 2">` because you already had data `category` in first step that will control what to display in the next step.

```html
<fieldset v-if="step == 1">
  // html of step 1
</fieldset>
<fieldset v-if="step == 2">
  <template v-if="category == 'real estate'">
   // form for this cateegory
  </template>
  <template v-else-if="category == 'IT'">
   // form for this category
  </template>
  // and so on
  . . .

</fieldset>
```

Comment: how can we connect category field with this template to prompt the form

Comment: this is the category field `<input style="width: 93%;" type="text" v-model="category" @change="onChange($event)" placeholder="Search your category"
                      name="category" maxlength="200" id="id_post_type">` , isnt this?

Comment: yeh but if we enter the category in the category field then any method is required to prompt the template

Comment: you want it changes to step 2 directly after user enters the category without clicking `next`?

Comment: i am not sure about your definition 'without any connection with template'. but you have defined `category` in `data()` right? so it can be accessed by any `<template v-if="">` as long as it is in same `.vue` file  or same component. So without using `onChange`, the `category` in step 2 should work

Comment: sorry maybe i dont get it

Comment: Thanks, Actually When I have filled first step with some category based on that category next form fields need be there. for example if user enters "Electronics | Mobile" based on that category I need form fields in next form. I hope you will get it know you will help to solve this requirement. Thank you.

Comment: Hi sir your solution is helped me a lot and I am continuing with your solution. But I have one small issue I have two radio button step after category is filled. So because of radio button step i was unable to prompt the form

Comment: <template> <h1 class="post_adttl">Consumer</h1> <input class="consumer_radio" type="radio"> <label>Personal Ad:</label> <p>Personal ads can be posted one ad per month, which will appear <br> with "sale by owner tag"</p><br> <input class="business_radio" type="radio"> <label>Business Ad:</label> <p>Do you want to upgrade to business account to post more <br>ads per month</p> </template>